# Laplace transform of limited integral

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, signal-processing

Assuming $\mathscr{L}(x(t)) = X(s)$ then I would like to know $Y(s)$, where $y(t)$ is

$y(t) = \int_{t-\Delta}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau $

I guess one can start in the following way (using the two-side laplace transform):

$y(t) = \int_{t-\Delta}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau =  \int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau - \int_{-\infty}^{t-\Delta} x(\tau) d\tau   $

Hence

$Y(s) = X(s)/s - Y_{unknown} (s) $

So what is the $Y_{unknown}(s)$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $t-\Delta$ and $t$ are both positive, you can express your integral as a difference of two integrals, one from $0$ to $t$ and another from $0$ to $t-\Delta$. Then you can use the standard tables of LT